# C# get Oracle Query execution time

Tags: c#, oracle

When connecting to a SQL Server Database in C# I get the query execution time like so:

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
                {
                    DataSource = "SERVER",
                    InitialCatalog = "DB",
                    UserID = "USER",
                    Password = "PASSWORD"
                }.ConnectionString);

                conn.StatisticsEnabled = true;

                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", conn);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


                    // execute the command

                    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    var stats = conn.RetrieveStatistics();

                  var milliSecs = (long)stats["ExecutionTime"];
               }
               catch(Execption e){

               }
```

But I cannot find a similar method to achieve this with a Oracle database.

I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559189/oracle-query-execution-time) but this does the timing on the database not in C#. (I don't have access to edit the queries I will be monitoring).

How can I achieve this? Is there an equivalent function in Oracle.DataAccess library?

Comment: Could you not just make a DateTime before execution and then yet another one after. Then just subtract them and then you got your execution time?..

Comment: @MartinM Stopwatch class is preferred to measure elapsed times as DateTime.Now has rather low precision: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-4.7.2