# How can I find out the query execution time in Oracle SQL using Toad?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am building an application that has a couple hundred select`s and I need to print in a report the query time.

I am using Oracle databases with Toad IDE.

Let`s say for example I have a "select * from names" and I would like to print the query execution time.

Thanks

I created a function in Java because I am generating the report with Java but it prints the execution that it calculates from Java not the exact database query execution time

I would like to print the query execution time

Comment: IIRC, run as a script, and put `set timing on` at the top of the script.

Comment: See this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559189/oracle-query-execution-time) - Possible duplicate of this question

Answer (score 3):

A simple option is to view "Query viewer" tab; it shows **execution time** for each statement you run.

If it is a script you run within TOAD, then you'll have to calculate it yourself by subtracting date *before* the statement from date *after* that statement. Those `DATE` values should be set to `SYSDATE`. Result is number of days so you'll have to recalculate it to display something *smarter* (hours, minutes, seconds).